# Algorithm to calculate route for indoor positioning system

Tags: indoor-positioning-system

I'm building an indoor positioning system using UWB. I get the data accurately from the hardware component. On the mobile app, I have a plan (2D image) of the floor and I have a destination. I already have the ratio of the real-word distance to image pixels (meters per pixel). Moreover, I have the obstacles pre-defined as rectangles. I'm stuck in calculating the path from **A** to **B**, given the *current and destination coordinate, ratio of meter/pixel and the obstacles.*

It doesn't have to be on a specific platform or language; pseudo-code is fine since I want to get the idea behind the algorithm. Is there an algorithm that produces an output resembling a route?

Answer (score 1):

You have to "map" your problem to general problem called [Shortest Path Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem). 
One of the most popular and efficient algorithms that solves this problem is [Dijkstra algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). So try to use it to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found also this very instructive: https://www.mdpi.com/2220-9964/7/4/133/pdf. I'm myself recreating a similar approach.